# How can Pillow open uploaded image file from StringIO directly?

Tags: python, flask, python-imaging-library, stringio

User upload a image file by the Form, I don't want to save original uploaded image file to disk, and resize image by Pillow opening image from disk.

I want to resize this image file in memory first, then save the resized image file to disk. so I import StringIO as buffer, but it does't work with Pillow.

Here is the code:

Python3.4, Flask==0.10.1, Pillow==3.4.2

## forms.py

```
class Form():
    img = FileField()
    submit = SubmitField()
```

## views.py

```
from io import StringIO
from PIL import Image
from .forms import Form

@app.route('/upload_img', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_img():
    form = Form()
    im = Image.open(StringIO(form.img.data.read())

    pass
```

---

> TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes

Answer (score 7):

From [Pillow docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#functions):

> `PIL.Image.open(fp, mode='r')`
>
> Opens and identifies the given image file. Parameters:
>
> `fp` – A filename (string), `pathlib.Path` object or a file object. The file object must implement `read()`, `seek()`, and `tell()` methods, and
> be opened in **binary** mode.

What you're passing to `open` is a `StringIO`. It creates a file-like object from an `str` object that is opened in *text* mode.
The issue is caused by the argument in `StringIO`. `form.img.data.read()` returns a `bytes` object, passing it into the constructor is forbidden. But in your case, a `StringIO` won't work.
Instead, use `io.BytesIO`. It has pretty much the same interface, except that it takes `bytes` objects and returns a file-like object opened in *binary* mode, which is what you need.

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image
from .forms import Form

@app.route('/upload_img', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_img():
    form = Form()
    im = Image.open(BytesIO(form.img.data.read())

    pass
```

Comment: yes, I'vd tried with BytesIO, but still with OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BytesIO object at 0x03B07880>

Comment: @rogwan then the data returned from `form.img.data.read()` is not a valid image. You can test that by simply opening a file in binary mode and writing the return value there. If the image will be corrupted, then you'll have to investigate why the image data isn't transferred properly

Comment: OK, thanks for your advices, open filestorage directly would be the ideal solution.